# Django container cannot find its mysql container

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I have built my django docker with hostname server_default and with --network=server_default and ran mysql with same network(mysql container has ran before django server) when I check my mysql container everything is ok but when I run my django server it fails with error :

```
"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server_default' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)"
```

I attached to my server container and I couldn't connect to mysql container.
server_default is a bridge type.
my run commands :

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --network=server_default scotech-server

sudo docker run -d --network=server_default scotech-db
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to add the actual `docker network` and `docker run` commands you ran?

Comment: I added , thanks for your fast response

Comment: The database in particular needs a `--name` parameter, and that container name can be used by the Django app as a DNS name to reach the database.  The network name on its own isn't enough.

Comment: I tried scotech-db as hostname but didn't work :( (my mysql name)

Comment: If you run `docker ps` you can find the generated `adjective_person` name of the container, and _that_ will work as a hostname.  But it'd be clearer to explicitly `docker run --name` the name you want.

Comment: [Use bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) in the Docker documentation explains this, though not especially clearly.  Even if you're not using Docker Compose, [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has a clearer description of the steps involved.

Comment: I am trying with docker-compose at the moment but CMD command ( python3 manage.py runserver) in Dockerfile doesn't run in docker-compose :| , I have tried with docker-compose more than two weeks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't do it with docker individually but with docker-compose.yml and 2 build context I could connect them together : it seems a bad solution :(

```
version: '3'

services:
scotech-db:
 build:
  context: ./scotech-mysql-docker
 expose:
  - 3306
 web:
  build:
   context: ./server
  depends_on:
   - scotech-db
  restart: on-failure
  ports:
   - "8002:8000"
```

Comment: This is a very routine 2-container setup (the `expose:` declaration is unnecessary).